# *SOLVED* How to execute a function after a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, click

I'm trying to subtract 1 life from the `lives` variable every time `buttonA` is clicked. But the `removeLives();` function executes before `buttonA` is clicked.

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="lives"></div>
    <button id="buttonA" onClick="removeLives()">buttonA</button>

<script>
  var lives = 3;

  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML="LIVES: " + removeLives();
  document.getElementById("buttonA").onClick = function(){
    removeLives() {
    lives--;
    return lives;
    }
  }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are calling removeLives() when loading the script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the interpreter runs the line `.innerHTML="LIVES: " + removeLives();`, `removeLives` will be called, resulting in `lives` being decremented and the new content there being lower.

Put that line inside the click handler instead, and initially populate the `lives` div via the HTML.

Also, either use an inline handler in the HTML or `.onclick` in the JS, but not both - preferably, avoid inline handlers, since they're universally considered to be poor practice. To add the handler in the JS, make sure to use `.onclick`, not `.onClick`, it's case sensitive.

You'll also probably want to stop decrementing once `lives` reaches 0.

```js
var lives = 3;
document.getElementById("buttonA").onclick = function() {
  lives--;
  if (lives < 0) lives = 0;
  document.getElementById("lives").innerHTML = "LIVES: " + lives;
};
```

```html
<div id="lives">LIVES: 3</div>
<button id="buttonA">buttonA</button>
```